# How do I get the lon/lat value in OpenLayers 5 on click

Tags: click, centering, openlayers-5, mouse-position

I try to receive the coordinates in lon/lat form an OpenLayer 5 map when i click on the map as an array or json with the values in order to set the map center to this clicked coordinates.
I tried to get the coordinates by this

```
var mousePosition = new OlMousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: createStringXY(2),
  projection: 'EPSG:25832',
});
```

But where in `mousePosition` are the coordinates stored? All examples I have found send the values via `target:` into a HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

As i got the Pixel coordinates I used now `getCoordinateFromPixel` from ol/Map to get the specific values and `map.getView().setCenter(coordinates)` to set the center.